# Primer not adhering to paint

Tags: painting, paint, repainting, primer

I am priming some walls which have two different paints exposed. The previous painter did not remove the coax cover plate when painting, and that older paint is causing problems for the primer. I'm using kilz2 latex primer.

Any ideas on a cause and a solution?
[image: dripping paint]
[image: primer can]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sand the problem area to scuff up the surface for better primer adhesion.

If that doesn't work or if it's possible that the underlying paint contains lead (which is not safe to sand) then an oil or shellac-based primer may work better.

Comment: You can sand leaded paint, just do it wet.  Use sandpaper made for wet sanding, or since you're only scuff sanding, just use a Scotchbrite "green" pad, they enjoy being wet.  Wipe the work area down with paper towels and throw them all in a plastic bag in the trash.  It's lead, not polonium. Just don't eat it.

Comment: Sanding didn't help in my case, but oil-based kilz got the job done